# Why is this receiver-configuration for the alertmanager in rancher invalid?

Tags: prometheus, webhooks, rancher, prometheus-alertmanager

I want that the alertmanager in rancher send me a webhook post after receiving a alert. Therefor I need an oauth2-config in my webhook-configuration like this:

```
- name: 'Name'
  webhook_configs:
    - url: 'url'
      http_config:
        oauth2:
          client_id: 'id'
          endpoint_params:
            grant_type: 'string'
          client_secret: 'secret'
          scopes:
            - 'string'
          token_url: 'url'
```

This is my local configuration for the webhook-receiver, which works fine on my local system. Local I have the same prometheus & alertmanager version like the ones I run in rancher. But it seems that the alertmanager in rancher don`t accept the configured receiver.yaml with the webhook. This is my receiver configuration in rancher:

```
  name: Name
  webhook_configs:
    - http_config:
        oauth2:
          client_id: 'id'
        tls_config: {}
      send_resolved: false
```

After a redeployment of my alertmanager I always get this configuration in alertmanager:

```
name: Name
  webhook_configs:
  - send_resolved: false
    http_config:
      follow_redirects: true
```

It seems that the oauth2-part is invalid and is missing, but I don't know why. The rest of the receiver configuration is correct and will be loaded correctly in the alertmanager configuration. But if I add the oauth2 part the receiver configuration will not be loaded by the alertmanager.

Prometheus version: 2.27.1, Alertmanager version: 0.22.2, Rancher version: 2.5.16

Is there anything I do wrong or forget?

I tried many different configurations for the receiver configuration, but it seems that the oauth2 part itself is invalid for this webhook configuration in rancher.

But according to the prometheus documents it should be possible:
[WebhookConfig docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#webhook_config),
[HttpConfig docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#http_config)